# I can't import logging dependancy into my project

Tags: spring, maven, intellij-idea

The import statements aren't working

[image]

I am new to Maven so I'm not sure what to do (if I'm missing a dependancy or something)

Comment: Have a read through this for inspiration for next time: https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/261592/how-much-research-effort-is-expected-of-stack-overflow-users

Answer (score 0):

Add this in the dependency section of your pom :

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>commons-logging</groupId>
    <artifactId>commons-logging</artifactId>
    <version>1.1.1</version>
</dependency>
```

There are other logging libraries available ,refer :
https://www.baeldung.com/java-logging-intro

Answer (score 0):

If you are using Spring, I'm not sure if need to add it. When I add the line

```
Log log = LogFactory.getLog(MYCLASS.class);
```

to a class & I choose "Import class" in IntelliJ, I can see that it refers to `org.springframework:spring-jcl:5.0.5.RELEASE`, so it seems to already be available through the Spring.jar .

If you want to try adding it you can add the following to your dependencies list in the pom:

```
<!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/commons-logging/commons-logging -->
<dependency>
    <groupId>commons-logging</groupId>
    <artifactId>commons-logging</artifactId>
    <version>1.2</version>
</dependency>
```

I would also point you to Log4j which is very popular & efficient. If you want to use that you need to do two things:

1. Add the dependencies to the pom:

   ```
   <dependency>
       <groupId>org.apache.logging.log4j</groupId>
       <artifactId>log4j-api</artifactId>
       <version>2.3</version>
   </dependency>

   <dependency>
       <groupId>org.apache.logging.log4j</groupId>
       <artifactId>log4j-core</artifactId>
       <version>2.3</version>
   </dependency>
   ```
2. Add a log4j.properties or log4j.xml file with configurations to the classpath (mine is in sr/main/resources).